# Solving the equation for $x$ given that $x \in \mathbb{R}, x > 0$

Tags: logarithms

Given that the product of $\log(x+3)$ and $\log(x-3)$ is equal to $3$; the logarithms are to the base of 3.

> $$
> \log_3(x+3)\log_3(x-3) = 3
> $$

Someone to help me solve for $x$?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't supposed to be the sum of those logarithms? If it's the product, there isn't a pretty answer.

Comment: Wolfram alpha cannot do it. $\implies$ No one can do it.

Comment: The product not sum

Comment: @Awesome [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Log%5Bx-3%5D*Log%5Bx%2B3%5D%29%2F%28Log%5B3%5D%29%5E2%3D3) just did it.

Comment: @metacompactness I meant in a form of known elementary functions.

Comment: Where did you find the question?

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$f(x)=\log_3(x+3) \times \log_3(x-3) - 3=0$$ cannot be solved analytically. Only numerical methods could be used for solving it. Plotting the function shows that there is a root in the range $7\lt x \lt 8$. A good candidate is Newton iterative scheme $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac {f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ Applied to this function and starting iterations at $x_0=7$ gives the following iterates : $7.60031$, $7.62747$, $7.62751$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

**Added later to this answer**

Even without plotting the function, it is obvious that the solution of the equation is larger than $6$ since $f(6)=-1$. So, iterations can start at this value and the successive Newton iterates are $7.41250$, $7.62449$, $7.62751$